# This is a python exercise where we separate all uppercase, lowercase, number, symbols etc. and print them as sub string

Tags: python, python-3.x

//Unfortunately cannot understand why the Output: HT. As of my observation, the program stops @ return uppercase; other returns are ignored. I have also used a print statement instead return and that gives expected outputs.

```
# input: Hello Test! 123 123, good.
# Output: expected
# Enter a string: Hello Test! 123 123, good.
# HT
# elloestgood
# 123123
# !  , .
#Version 1

def letter_type(a_string):
    uppercase = ""
    lowercase = ""
    digit = ""
    other = ""
    for alphabet in a_string:
        if alphabet.isupper():
            uppercase += alphabet
        elif alphabet.islower():
            lowercase += alphabet
        elif alphabet.isdigit():
            digit += alphabet    
        else:
            other += alphabet
            
    return uppercase
    return lowercase
    return digit
    return other
a_string = letter_type(input("Enter a string: "))

print(a_string)
```

//This is version 2 where I have used print instead of return function. Please consider me as a beginner.

```
# input: Hello Test! 123 123, good.
# Output: expected
# Enter a string: Hello Test! 123 123, good.
# HT
# elloestgood
# 123123
# !  , .
#Version 2

def letter_type(a_string):
    uppercase = ""
    lowercase = ""
    digit = ""
    other = ""
    for alphabet in a_string:
        if alphabet.isupper():
            uppercase += alphabet
        elif alphabet.islower():
            lowercase += alphabet
        elif alphabet.isdigit():
            digit += alphabet
        else:
            other += alphabet
    print(uppercase)
    print(lowercase)
    print(digit)
    print(other)
a_string = input("Enter a string: ").strip()
letter_type(a_string)
```

Comment: Please edit your question. It seems unclear what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To count the time a sub-string occurs inside a string use the `count` method.

```
from __future__ import print_function
file_name = 'learning_python.txt'

with open(file_name) as file_object:
    lines = file_object.readlines()

    pi_string = ''.join(lines)
    print(pi_string)

    word = 'python'     
    if pi_string.count(word) == 3:
        print('The word used 3 times is:\n {}'.format(word))
    else:
        print('No words used thrice.')
```

This will give you:

```
The word used 3 times is:
 python
```

Comment: @MehediHossain this is just an example of how to apply it to a string. In your case foo will be the `lines` variable. If you can refactor your code to be more readable then I might be able to give a more specific answer.

Comment: @MehediHossain check my updated answer. Also comments in python are done with a `#` according to PEP8, i.e `# This is a comment`

Comment: @MehediHossain im glad to hear it helped. If my answer helped please mark it as the accepted answer as this will help other SO users as well.